# How to resolve this component?

Tags: android

Error : Failed to resolve com.android.supprt:appcompat-v7:28.0.1

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {

```
compileSdkVersion 23

buildToolsVersion "28.0.1"

defaultConfig {

    applicationId "com.example.dell.swipelistview"

    minSdkVersion 23

    targetSdkVersion 23

    versionCode 1

    versionName "1.0"
}

buildTypes {

    release {

        minifyEnabled false

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),
```

'proguard-rules.pro'

```
    }

}
```

}

dependencies {

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You have to add maven repository in build.gradle (project)

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
    ...
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I did it. I solved it by reducing the size of the SDK version.

Answer (score 0):

You have to download 28.0.1 build tools version from sdk manager or you are in offline mode. or use this :

allprojects {
    repositories {
        .......
        google()
        .......
    }
}

Comment: I did it. I solved it by reducing the size of the SDK version.

Comment: But you need to update your version for Android 9 or above